# Why is my iOS app getting launched automatically?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, background-task

I have an audio app that plays when being launched. It has CarPlay entitlements, plays from the network and naturally plays in the background.

Now, every one in a while the phone launchs the app in the background without notice. Music simply starts to play randomly. I can't determine the cause or the situation in which this reproduces. It might be related to Bluetooth connections, phone calls, CarPlay interactions, network changes or other reasons.

I do know the following things for sure:

- The app is launched from scratch as I have examined remote logs and seen the app is being launched.
- Pausing the music from control center will kill the app, and it will be relaunching after 2-3 minutes again (and again)

Answer (score 0):

There are not too many clues about your issue.
But I would try to find some possible causes base on my experiences.

First of all, check the notifications/listeners that you use in the app.
Something would be like bellow:

```objectivec
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification  object:nil];
```

for this one, once the network status changed, you would get the notification, and you might do something after that(play the music).

Second, check out if there is `Timer` in the app or not, it would cause problem if
the timer was set improperly and you do something by the timer.

Comment: I can rule out this is related to notifications or timers because I can see in the logs that when this issue occurs the app is _launched_, not resumed. Unless you know these have a the capability of launching an app.